# Explain the output?

Tags: c, increment, decrement

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a = 10;

printf("%d %d %d",++a,a++,a--);

return 0;
}
```

I edited the code a bit..now the outputs are : 11 9 10
It's more complex now..

Comment: Why do you think it happens that way? What is not clear?

Comment: Explanation:Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's up to the compiler in which order he evaluates the parameters of a function call.**

---

If the compiler goes from left to right (that would explain your output):

- *a* is 10
- prä-increment which means *a* is incremented (the value 11 is passed as parameter)
- post-decrement which means *a* is decremented **later** (the the value 11 is passed as parameter)
- post-increment which means *a* is incremented **later** (the value 10 is passed as parameter)

But if I compile this e.g. with another compiler I could get different output.

Comment: Wrong. Hint: sequence points.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting it as follows may make it easier to understand:

**NOTE: I have made the assumption that the compiler will produce code to evaluate the parameters from left to right! This may be compiler specific.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int param2, param3, param4;

    param2 = ++a;  // increments a to 11 and evaluates to 11
    param3 = a--;  // evaluates to current value of a then decrements a (11)
    param4 = a++;  // evaluates to current value of a then increments a (10)

    printf("%d %d %d",param2,param3,param4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The place of increment(++) and decrement(--) operator is very important. So in case of ++a the value is incremented from 10 to 11 and then printed, for a-- the current value is printed i.e. 10 and then the a is incremented to 11. Similarly in last case a++ current value 11 is printed and it is incremented to 12.